# Visual Studio 2019 Linker tab not showing Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

In a normal C++ project you can specify a library in `Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies` (image 1), but while working with Unreal Engine, in project property the tab for `Linker` isn't there (image 2). I was able to add the options from `C/C++/General/Additional Include Directories` (image 3) to `VC++ Directories/Include Directories` (image 4) but I still need to add the library as well, so can anyone explain how can I do this?

C/C++ isn't what I normally use, and so in Unreal Engine I'm using blueprints to get around this, but for some things I still need to use it and write code like in this case.

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Image 3:
[image]

Image 4:
[image]

Comment: These are the settings for a makefile project, not a regular VS project.  Making changes requires editing the makefile.  The NMake settings tell you where it is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case i wanted to use `jvm.lib` that is located in the folder `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_333\\lib`, and to do that the solution was this:

- Go to this location: *ProjectFolder\Source\ProjectName*
- There open the file: **ProjectName.Build.cs**
- Then inside it in `public ProjectName(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target) { }` I had to add the following lines:

  ```
    PublicDefinitions.Add("WITH_MYTHIRDPARTYLIBRARY=1");

    PublicIncludePaths.Add(Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_333\\include"));
    PublicIncludePaths.Add(Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_333\\include\\win32"));

    PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_333\\lib\\jvm.lib"));
  ```

As a side note, don't forget to add double \\ in paths, I was in a rush and I only used one \ and it took me a few moments to realize what the error was about.

Answer (score 0):

You can add external libs by modifying your modules build settings In "YourModuleName.Build.cs" add something like

```
PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add("<somelibPath>.lib");
PublicIncludePaths.Add("<includeDirectory>");
```

[Unreal module docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProductionPipelines/BuildTools/UnrealBuildTool/ModuleFiles/)